# uncheck field at midnight

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a custom object with a checkbox field that gets set to true when a record is inserted when a certain condition is met via a trigger.  Once the field is set to true, other processing is bypassed until the checkbox is unchecked.

I need to uncheck the field on each new day at midnight, so the following day the processing can occur normally until it hits a specific condition (threshold), the field will be once again flagged and all processing will be bypassed until the checkbox is unchecked again, which needs to happen every night at midnight.

So, I know I can create a batch program and schedule it nightly to uncheck the field for all records.  However, I'm wondering if this can be achieved declaratively?  Is there a way to accomplish this with a time-based workflow or some other declarative option that can uncheck the field for every record at midnight?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4):

A time-based workflow with a field update perfectly fits for this type of criteria. 
Have you tried it ? If yes what problem did you encountered.
Sorry for putting as an answer still can't comment :(

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem you are having is that Time based workflow must be relative to a field or event.

The way I see it is that you have two main options:

- Create a field (formula or otherwise) and populate that with a datetime you can reference in the workflow.
- Use scheduled apex.

Personally I would use the scheduled apex because I'm not a fan of adding fields to achieve workflow.